# Fan speed Thinkpad with Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, fan, fancontrol

I bought a new ThinkPad with AMD Ryzen™ 7 (4000 Series). I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with the newest kernel 5.8.0-43-generic.

I have the feeling that my fan is running at max speed all the time. Even when I closed all windows and do nothing I can still hear it. My question is: Is this normal? On my old laptop (which was much worse than my new one) I could not hear the fan when I was not doing anything.

I monitored the fan speed with "hardinfo" and it is constantly around 2680 RPM. Is this normal?

To test everything I opened 4 youtube videos at the same time. The CPU goes up in this case:

[image]

However the fan speed stays constant...

[image]

I have the feeling that something is not working correctly!?

Edit: Information about Processor

[image]

Comment: You can't make an equal comparison to your other laptop unless it was identical.  Generally, the more powerful the laptop, the louder it will be.  "Gaming" laptops routinely sound like a jet engine, while laptops with low power CPUs like the Intel N5000 are often fanless and completely silent.  You might consider checking the motherboard BIOS for fan speed settings.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: It is not a gaming laptop

Comment: What **exactly** is the model CPU in your laptop?

Comment: I added a screenshot which answers your question.

Comment: There's a trade-off between power and noise, especially in laptops where everything is crammed in a tiny chassis.  Laptops are designed for portability so there's not room for a larger (quieter) cooling system. If you put a powerful 8 core, 16 thread CPU in a tiny box, it's going to be loud to keep it from overheating. Your laptop is designed for high performance at the expense of more noise and lower battery life.

Comment: To be hones I still think something is not working. When I close the Laptop and open it again the fan is not working at all... So I think there is something wrong.

Comment: Another update: It seems like that the fan increases at some points when necessary but does not decrease if everything is closed...

Comment: It might not ever turn off. Did you go through your motherboard BIOS / firmware settings?  That's usually how fan speeds are controlled, if they can be controlled.  This is a feature of your hardware and not associated with Ubuntu or any other operating system. You can usually access these settings by interrupting the boot process. Read the documentation for your device to figure out how to access these settings.

Comment: Sharing arbitrary comment: I had the same problem, and tried everything including installing and tuning thinkfan (did not help), updating bios (did not help), adjusting power mode to "power saver" (helped quite a bit but slowed down performance). I noticed the fan noise only appeared when connected to an external monitor. To my surprise, replacing my old monitor with a **new and modern monitor** removed almost all excessive fan noise.